# Association does not work in package environment

Tags: packages, output

I'm trying to be sneaky with a function and try to have an expression stored as a string (unevaluated) until a desired moment when it will be converted from a string to an expression and then have it parsed.

I am doing this because some computations are quite heavy and depending on what I want from the function I can either get the "a" or "b" outputs/paths. I suspect that `SetDelayed` or `TagSetDelayed` would probably be better suited here, but I'm not certain how to use them in this context.

This works beautifully as a normal function (non-packaged) in a notebook (v.13.2) however the moment I introduce this idea in a package environment, it fails to parse it.

### The packaged version:

```
BeginPackage["SE`Question`"];
func1; (* declared in public part of package *)
Begin["`Private`"];
func1[a_,b_,output_:"a"]:=Block[{range,data1,data2,dict,dat1,dat2},
range=Range[10];
data1 = Table[i^a,{i,10}];
data2 = Table[i^b,{i,10}];
dict=<|
"a"->"{range,data1}\[Transpose]",
"b"->"{range,data2}\[Transpose]"
|>;
ToExpression[Evaluate[dict[output]]]
]
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

### The non-packaged version

```
Clear[func2]
func2[a_,b_,output_:"a"]:=Block[{range,data1,data2,dict},
range=Range[10];
data1 = Table[i^a,{i,10}];
data2=Table[i^b,{i,10}];
dict=<|
"a"->"{range,data1}\[Transpose]",
"b"->"{range,data2}\[Transpose]"
|>;
ToExpression[Evaluate[dict[output]]]
]
```

### Output

```
func1[2,4,"a"] (* the packaged function *)
func2[2,4,"a"]  (* the non-packaged function *)
```

[image]

If someone could please explain why this happens or better yet suggest an alternative I would be very grateful.

Comment: It seems that replacing the association part with ```dict=<|
"a"->out1,
"b"->out2
|>;
Evaluate[dict[output]]/.{out1:>{range,data1}\[Transpose],out2:>{range,data2}\[Transpose]}``` using `RuleDelayed` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

When you evaluate

```
BeginPackage["SE`Question`"]
```

it resets the $ContextPath (EndPackage resets it back). A consequence of this is that when new symbols are encountered they will be in the

```
SE`Question
```

context. So, in your Block, the symbol data1 is (fully qualified)

```
SE`Question`data1
```

Now, when you're back in the Global context and you evaluate func1[2, 4, "a"], the data1 string becomes the data1 symbol, but that symbol fully qualified is

```
Global`data1
```

So, it doesn't have the value that you expect (and apparently is undefined, which is why it just displays as itself without resolving to some other value).

## The simple fix

Just don't wrap your expressions in strings:

```
BeginPackage["AnotherSE`Question`"];
func4; (*declared in public part of package*)
Begin["`Private`"];
func4[a_, b_, output_ : "a"] := 
Block[
  {range, data1, data2, dict, dat1, dat2}, 
  range = Range[10];
  data1 = Table[i^a, {i, 10}];
  data2 = Table[i^b, {i, 10}];
  dict = <|"a" -> Transpose[{range, data1}], "b" -> Transpose[{range, data2}]|>;
  dict[output]]
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

## The slightly better fix

In general, one should be careful to understand how variables are localized and to avoid letting local variables "leak". In your case, you don't need all of those extraneous variables at all.

```
BeginPackage["NewSE`Question`"];
func3; (*declared in public part of package*)
Begin["`Private`"];
func3[a_, b_] := func3[a, b, "a"];
func3[a_, _, "a"] := theRealStuff[a];
func3[_, b_, "b"] := theRealStuff[b];
func3[___] := "func3 is undefined for these arguments";
theRealStuff[x_] := Transpose[{Range[10], Range[10]^x}];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

But even this is really awkward. A function that doesn't depend on some of its arguments should be a red flag. Maybe this is just a consequence of you trying to simplify your real problem, but if this is truly representative of what you're trying to do, then a better pattern would be to make the choice of which value to pass to the function *outside* of the function, as opposed to using a flag to choose which argument to process *inside* the function. But since you haven't shown us the larger context in which you'd choose the "a" or "b" flags, I don't have a demonstration for how to do that.

Comment: Hi @lericr! Thank you for your response. I suspected that I was messing with some Context, but could not troubleshoot it. I cannot understand why data1 would be in Global` as it is defined explicitely within Block. Why would that suddenly change?

As for what i'm trying to do, I wanted to have a function that is my "go-to-do-all" Fourier function. Sometimes I want the frequency component, sometimes I want the phase component. My dirty workaround was the association trick which apparently does not like being in a package!

Comment: The association is a red herring--that has nothing to do with the failure here.

Comment: Yes, data1 was inside a block. It was also inside a package definition, so it's fully qualified name had that package name as its context. But you executed the function in the Global context, and that is the moment when the string was turned into an expression. So, when the evaluator "saw" the symbol data1, it interpreted it as being in the Global context.

Comment: So, what you could do (I don't think it's a good idea, but it will work and will maybe help demonstrate what's going on), is inside your definition for func1, replace the string range with the string SE'Question'range and similarly for data1 and data2. (those single quotes should be backticks, but backticks make this comment formatted awkwardly.)

Comment: "So, when the evaluator "saw" the symbol data1, it interpreted it as being in the Global context." I'm very confused from this. What is the purpose of the package and the Block if the variables defined within it are seen as Global`? Doesn't the evaluation take place in the specific context of the package (or block)? If data1 is seen as Global` then so should every other variable defined within it, no? Am I missing something very basic?

Comment: You coded func1[...]:=.... The := is SetDelayed, so the right hand side doesn't get evaluated until the function is invoked. But "stuff" still happens when you evaluate such an expression, in particular, symbols need to be resolved. I get wrapped around the axle on these things too, so my analysis might not be perfect, but I believe that your symbols as used to define func1 were in the SE`Question context.

Comment: But when func1 was invoked, you were in the Global context. Since what got evaluated was turning strings into expressions, those symbols in the strings were opaque until func1 exposed them via ToExpression. And so they ended up in the Global context. And thus, they masked the symbols you intended to be used.

Comment: Side note here. The way Mathematica localizes symbols is by very specific naming schemes. All symbols are global (not in the Global context--by "global" I mean accessible anywhere/anytime if you use the right name). People use the scoping constructs like Module and Block as if they were "true" localization constructs, but they aren't really. The upshot is that unless you're careful, symbols can easily leak or be masked. I generally avoid using these "localizing" constructs unless there is a compelling reason to use them. And in your case, it was completely unnecessary.

Comment: I mean, if you want the simplest fix, just don't use strings in your dict association. I guess I've been glossing over that because I didn't want to encourage this style of programming with excessive interim symbols.

Comment: That is quite informative.  The reason I tend to use Block is because I want to ensure that whatever variables I use will not overlap with anything I might have or will have. I generally find such constructs very important in any level of programming, but programming styles evolve and I am not sure if I'm catching up to them. You're quite right about the strings! It is a dirty way of doing it, but did not know if there is a better way to do that without actually computing what is needed. Multiple functions might be the better way forward really.

Comment: "I tend to use Block because I want to ensure that whatever variables I use will not overlap with anything I might have or will have". The better way is to make your functions depend only on their arguments (and other previously defined functions).